# preg_replace against string containing greater/less than signs

Tags: regex, preg-replace

I'm currently using this regex to match doi strings in reference text:

```
(10[.][0-9]{4,}[^\s"/<>]*/[^\s"<>]+)
```

This works well for most doi's, such as:

> Dahlin, J., Nissink, W., et al. (Jan 2015). PAINS in the Assay:
>   Chemical Mechanisms of Assay Interference and Promiscuous Enzymatic
>   Inhibition Observed during a Sulfhydryl-Scavenging HTS. J. Med. Chem.,
>   2015, 58 (5), pp 2091–2113. doi:10.1021/jm5019093

returns: `10.1021/jm5019093`

The same regex [returns a partial doi](http://regexr.com/3amaj) on this string:

> Schmoe, J., Doe, J., & McFly, M. (Jan 2011). Should adults with
>   children eat more chocolate ice cream?. Fancy Pants Journal, 33,
>   211-7. doi:10.1234/0867-5309(2001)039<0215:NINPHD>2.1.CO;3

returns `10.1234/0867-5309(2001)039`

I am expecting `10.1234/0867-5309(2001)039<0215:NINPHD>2.1.CO;3`

What do I need to do to account for the greater/left than symbols?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove them from the character class:

```
(10[.][0-9]{4,}[^\s"/]*/[^\s"]+)
```

Comment: Probably could write this as `(10\.\d{4,}[^/]*/[^\s"]+)`

Comment: @hwnd: Probably, but I've just kept characters from OP.